# Azure CloudTable.ExecuteQuery doesn't return results

Tags: c#, .net, azure

```
TableQuery<Entity> query = new TableQuery<Entity>()
    .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, KeyValue));

var items = m_table.ExecuteQuery (query);
return items.ToList ();
```

Azure CloudTable doesn't return any result and gets stuck at .ToList () statement. Any possible reason?

Comment: What about the 'KeyValue' in your code? I have tested your code, your code works right, the result like this:https://image.ibb.co/h14vdx/tableresult.gif. Is your storage connection string  right?  Or you  have some code not provided?

Comment: In my case, KeyValue is a Guid and In console this code works for me but for CloudServiceApp this gets stuck on ToList() method.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, we know the code is fine. I suppose there are some issues when you configure your Cloud Service APP project. I suggest you could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started) to check your configure steps.

Comment: If it is helpful, you could mark it as answer to close this thread.